# Stripe Destination charge, how to set description for connected account

Tags: stripe-payments

We build a platform for sellers and customers.

- The customers should be able to use different payment methods.
- The sellers should receive money for their invoices, but should *not* see customer data.

With Stripe, that called a [destination charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) where the platform charges the customer, but the actual money is routed to the seller. The seller then sees he's been paid the amount, but not by whom (apart from "through our platform").

I'm using Stripe.NET in our C# ASP.NET backend, but my question is not technology related.

I can [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create) to do exactly as described above.

Example code:

```
var stripeCharge = stripeChargeService.Create(
                new Stripe.ChargeCreateOptions
                    {
                        Amount = (int)(price * multiplier),
                        Currency = currency,
                        CustomerId = stripeCustomer.Id,
                        SourceId = source,
                        Destination = new Stripe.ChargeDestinationCreateOptions 
                                      {
                                          Account = stripeSellerId 
                                      },
                        StatementDescriptor = "PLATFORM: " + invoiceNumber,
                        Description = "PLATFORM Payment for invoice number " + invoiceNumber,
                        Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> 
                                   {
                                        { "InvoiceNumber", invoiceNumber } 
                                   }
                    });
```

When I do this, it works. I can see the charge in my platform account. I can see the payment in my seller's account. But the seller does not get any information that I provided. The "Description" and "Metadata" only show up in my platform account's charge. The sellers payment only says "123.45€". Uh... great... who paid their invoice? Matter of fact I don't care *who*. But **which invoice was paid** seems to be a **core requirement** for everybody building a platform or selling on it.

I checked the documentation of Stripe.NET and I checked if maybe it's older than the stripe API itself. But there is no parameter I could set. Nothing in the `ChargeDestinationCreateOptions` I could set (something like DestinationDescription for example).

The description field for the seller exists, I can see it in the dashboard, but it's empty. So what am I missing?

**How do I set the description or metadata of payment the seller can see in their account when doing a "destination charge"?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a destination charge with Stripe, there are three objects created:

- a charge object(`ch_xxx`) on the platform account
- a transfer object(`tr_xxx`) on the platform account representing the transfer to  the destination connected account.
- a payment object(`py_xxx`, which is equivalent on an API level to a charge object) on the connected account, representing the funds from the transfer being paid to that account.

From your description, it sounds like it is the third object here that you would like to set metadata or a description on? You're right, you can't do this directly in the parameters of creating a destination charge. However, once the charge is created, you can easily get a reference to the created payment and update it with the needed fields:

```
var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
chargeService.ExpandTransfer = true;

var chargeOptions = new StripeChargeCreateOptions
{
    Amount = 1000,
    Currency = "usd",
    SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId = "tok_visa",
    Description = "Payment for Invoice #42",
    Destination = "acct_1DHFyLAXrgjEhAUx",
    DestinationAmount = 800
};
var charge = chargeService.Create(chargeOptions);
var paymentId = charge.Transfer.DestinationPaymentId;
var paymentUpdateOptions = new StripeChargeUpdateOptions
{
    Description = "Payment for Invoice #42"
};
chargeService.Update(paymentId, paymentUpdateOptions, new StripeRequestOptions
{
    StripeConnectAccountId = "acct_1DHFyLAXrgjEhAUx"
});
```

The key point here is that a charge object links to the [transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object?lang=dotnet#charge_object-transfer), and the transfer links to the [payment](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/object?lang=dotnet#transfer_object-destination_payment). So by combining that with the [expanding object feature](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=dotnet) of the API, you can get access to the payment and update it!

Comment: Hi @karllekko. Did you find this functionality documented anywhere? I'm trying to do the exact same thing using stripe-ruby, where `Stripe::Charge.update` accepts both a `params` and an `opts` object as arguments, and the `opts` object, in which I presumably need to pass the `StripeConnectAccountId` seems totally undocumented on https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/update?lang=ruby or in the gem itself.

Comment: @UpQuark  it would be `stripe_account` in Ruby : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header The GitHub page describes that hash : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/master/README.md#per-request-configuration

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with Python? I can't seem to use a charge to update the payment via a payment_id.

Comment: Should just be https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/update?lang=python + https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication i.e. `stripe.Charge.modify("py_123",Description="Payment for Invoice #42", stripe_account="acct_xxx")` I don't really know what ` use a charge to update the payment via a payment_id.` means without seeing a full example of what you're trying(maybe ask a new question).

Comment: @karllekko yes, that's exactly what I've been trying but I get an error "No such charge: 'py_1Hxxx'"

Comment: If you get "no such" errors 99% of the time it means you are doing something wrong with your API keys and the stripe_account option. In this question, we're working with a Charge object that exists on a connected account (the arrival of the transferred funds). So you use your own platform account's secret key, and set stripe_account to the ID of the connected account. So I'd make sure you're doing that, and that if you set stripe_account to a variable, that the variable is not null for example. If you share the req_xxx request ID from the error with Stripe support they can help too

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed the stripe_account param in your previous comment. Adding that did the trick, although it seems to be undocumented.